# doctrine 2 with CodeIgniter 2 No Metadata classes to process

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I use CodeIgniter 2 with doctrine 2 and this is the project that I am working in

https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-2-with-Doctrine-2

I need to generate Entity classes from existing Database

so I configured the Doctrine to be in development mode and I set the Database on the CodeIgniter

after that I write this command

php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database annotation models/generated

the classes generated correctly from database but without any method,after that I write this command for generating entities

php doctrine orm:generate-entities --regenerate-entities="1" models/generated

but I find this error "No Metadata classes to process"

Thanks.

Comment: You have to set correct mapping driver configuration. Generating mapping doesn't mean they're already in the expected location.

Comment: could you please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

In the entity files generated, you neet do delete "use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;"

and replace "ORM\" with ""

Answer (score 0):

In Doctrine.php in libraries folder add these lines, to load the driver:

```
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\PHPDriver(APPPATH.'models/Mappings');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

Create your [Mapping files](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html).
And [generate entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#command-overview):

```
php cli-doctrine.php orm:generate-entities models --generate-annotations=true
```

Now you can create tables in your db:

```
php cli-doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of doctrine documentation and tutorials are not correct. You should use this command:

```
php doctrine orm:generate:entities --generate-annotations=true models/generated
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct line of code try now:

```
php doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=true models/generated
```